# Hide a value or data on table

Tags: extensions, mysql, module-display, front-end, user-groups

I'm using this Mshah frontend user manager extension.
I have below table and I want to hide the "Registered" value from that column, is that possible?

[image]

As you can see, the third column is a user group title that a user belongs to, and I want to hide the Registered value if possible.

```
if ($isAdmin || $groupNames=='ums') {
       $query="SELECT a.*,CASE a.block WHEN 0 THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive' END as status,group_concat(b.group_id) as ucheckbox,group_concat(c.title) as title,c.id as groupid from `#__users` a left join `#__user_usergroup_map` b on a.id=b.user_id left join `#__usergroups` c on b.group_id=c.id group by a.id ORDER BY a.id ASC";
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $rows=$db->loadObjectList();
        return $rows;
    }
```

Above is the mysql query code but I don't think can use NOT IN or <> as it is filtering the results instead.

Comment: Rather than edit the query, you should remove the column from the view PHP file

Comment: I still want to show other values though.. Only that I don't want to show "Registered" which is unnecessary to me.

Comment: Yup, I'd still probably edit this in the view. Maybe write a conditional statement, for example `if ($group != 'Registered') { // Display the group }`

Comment: Ah I mean, even they are in "Registered" group, I still want to display them, it's just that I don't want to display the "Registered" word on it haha.. Your code above seems like will display only other users that is not in "Registered" group..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do it is by overriding the view template.

1 - First you have to understand how to create an override of a component view.

This tutorial may help you:

https://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/overrides/

2 - Then you have to locate the code that renders the table.

There is not much we can do here without seeing the code, but I assume that you may have something like:

```
<td><?php echo $userGroups ?></td>
```

Again, this can be written in very different ways.

3 - Finally, change the output in order to eliminate "Registered"

```
<td><?php echo str_replace('Registered','',$userGroups) ?></td>
```

I hope this can give you a clue how to solve it.

Comment: I used your no 3. solution and it worked!!! THX!

Comment: Glad to hear that!